# Root Certificate of website through openssl command

Tags: ssl, certificate, authorization

I am trying to obtain the root certificate of various websites for my project, but I am not sure the certificates that I am getting back with this command, contains root certificate or not?

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect google.com:443
```

I was searching for an answer when I came across a post where wget was used to get the root certificate from the certificate repository of godaddy

```
wget https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/gd_bundle.crt -O ~/.cert/mail.nixcraft.net/gd.pem
```

how do i find the repository for every website?

Answer (score 2):

The server must include the certification chain during TLS connection (https). **The chain may include the CA root certificate, but it is optional**, So you have no guarantee that it will be available. The TLS protocol expects the client to have the certificate in their truststore to verify the trust

You can download the server certificate of every site programmatically, but it is needed to look for the root CA certificate. As you can see, godaddy publish them in its website. In many cases the certificate itself includes a reference to download the root certificate

Comment: I want to obtain the certificate from particular websites and then use it to verify others on the list, can I do that without getting root certificate?

Comment: For example, if a site has a chain of 3 certificates `0-root`, `1-intermediate`, and `2-leaf`, the server will provide you `2`,`1` (in this order). You can verify that `2` is signed by `1`. And if you have root, then verify that `1` is signed by `0`. Is this what you want to do?

Comment: @NikhilJain, is clear my answer? Do you need any further clarification?

Comment: Actually I want to verify the websites in the list that are using the same root certificate.. for that purpose I require the root certificate

Comment: If you do not have a key store with the root certificates you can compare the issuer name of the last certificate of the chain. The issuer name must match the subject of the CA root certificate